# Nativescript on Wear OS 2

Tags: firebase, push-notification, nativescript, rendering, wear-os

I play with NativeScript on Wear OS2.

I just took the NS HelloWorld (typescript non frameworks) and I added the Firebase plugin to get a simple text from the notification and display it in textbox.

All okay, except when the app resumes from background, in that case the UI does not render the text change.

Debugging, I see the notification payload coming up to my typescript page instance, no errors... But the UI doesn't render it.

If I run the same app on a phone, all works as expected also resuming from background. Same code, no one line difference.

I am wondering if NativeScript does support Wear OS...

Any thoughts about that?

Thanks, Fabio.

---

**Some code...**

//main-page.ts

```
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
     //here Firebase is already init, all right...
    (<Page>args.object).bindingContext = (new ViewModel).init();
}
```

//view-model.ts

```
import { Observable } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { NotificationService } from "./notification-service";

export class ViewModel extends Observable {

    private _message: string = "Waiting message...";

    init(): ViewModel {
        //this callback is always invoked as expected
        //also when the app is killed and comes back to life
        NotificationService.onMessage = (firebaseMessage: any) => {
            const text = firebaseMessage['text'] || firebaseMessage['data']['text'];

            console.log('text' + text);
            this.message = text; //that's okay, see setter below
        }

        return this;
    }

    get message(): string {
        return this._message;
    }

    set message(value: string) {
        if (this._message !== value) {
            this._message = value;

            //to this point the UI should update... BUT
            //it works only IF the app is in foreground
            //AND was never killed/backgrounded before.
            //(bug on wear-os only)
            this.notifyPropertyChange("message", value);
        }
    }
}
```

//main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" class="page">

    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Label text="{{ message }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: Can you share correspondent code, how / when you update the UI.

Comment: Code shared... thanks. I can share the project too but as you can see it is just the NS HelloWorld sample with Firebase added to it.

Comment: Are you testing it with firebase data message Or notification? Do you click on the notification to bring the app foreground, which triggers onMessage?

Comment: Yes, works like that. The notification flow goes well and data come to the page instance, the . message var is updated in the code but UI doesn't render again to reflect model change